# Can I be homosexual and still be a Christian?

Tags: biblical-basis, homosexuality

I am struggling with certain personal aspects of my life, and almost every Christian I ask about this issue seems to be against it. I know there are some few Christian people that are in favour of homosexuality, but they appear to be a minority. This is very important for me, because I understand the Bible does say things about this, but no one I asked (neither those for it nor those against it) has given me the biblical basis for their stance. Some people say I shouldn't worry about what the Bible has to say on the matter, but I am concerned about this, not simply going to church and worshipping but also applying principles to my life. I believe this is the way Christianity should be practised.